# Even Ideals in ring of integers of a number field

Tags: number-theory, field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Say L is a number field and its ring of integers is $\mathcal{O}_{L}$. Call a prime ideal I $\subset\mathcal{O}_{L}$ even iff | $\mathcal{O}_{L}$/I | is even iff  | $\mathcal{O}_{L}$/I | is a power of 2. [Last iff is due to basic ANT]

For example for L = $\mathbb{Q}[i]$ and $\mathcal{O}_{L}$ = $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ then only even prime ideal is $\langle 1+i \rangle$.

Similarly, I was trying to see what kind of number fields will have how many even prime ideals (or none). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand your "basic ant" can you explain? For instance is the ideal 6 even in any ring of integers? Do you only want to consider prime $I$?

Comment: At least if you restrict to prime ideals $I$ then it is true that $|\mathcal{O}_L/I|$ is a prime power, because $\mathcal{O}_L/I$ is a finite field. I think the criterion is that a prime ideal is even if and only it contains $2$. So you basically have to look at the splitting of $(2)$ in $\mathcal{O}_L$.

Comment: @TobErnack yeah, prime ideals are the only one I am bothered about.

Comment: @TobErnack has put their finger on it. The possibilities are that there are $g$ primes above $2$, where $1\le g\le[L:\Bbb Q]$, and  after a little thought I realized that all possibilities occur (never none). I’ll hope that somebody can quote a theorem, but if not, I can show you how to do it. As often happens in these cases, Newton Polygon rides in on its white horse to deliver the goods.

Comment: @Lubin First of all, I really like your description "aged mathematician". I am going to use that someday and quote you. I worked out how $\langle$ 2 $\rangle$ factors in quadratic ideals (it took me a while). Now I am getting a little ambitious and do want to see how one could do the same for other number fields. 
I would be really grateful if you help me a little.

Comment: Well, I’ve been retired for 20 years. If you want a fairly full proof of my claim, I can give a proper answer below. Or you can e-mail me, and it would be more like a conversation.

Comment: I will email you by tonight then. Yes of course, I like learning through conversation.